# regarding the http post method to put data inside a json file in asset folder of my angular 2 project

Tags: json, angular, http

i have a json file named query.json in my asset folder of my angular project when i use http get i receive the data with body as empty now i want to insert data into that file but when i use put it says 404 file not found

my code is like this:

```
this.http.put('./assets/localfilestorage/query.json',this.savedmodel).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Data Uploaded!");
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error occured");
      });

    this.config = this.http.get('./assets/localfilestorage/query.json');
      this.config.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: You can't just insert data in a static file like that...

Comment: ok thanks, Then how read and write data into a locally stored static file using angular

Comment: You need some server side code to do that. Angular will just call the write/read methods